# How to make OpenAPI schema's property required on GET but optional on POST?

Tags: openapi

Is it possible to make one schema in OpenAPI in such a way that a property is required on GET but optional on POST? In this example I want my_property to be required on GET but optional on POST.

```
MySchedule:
 type: object
 properties:
  my_property:
   type: string
```

Comment: you need to share more information where this property is used.  as a path parameter, query parameter?  in a response schema?

Answer (score -1):

In OpenAPI, a schema's property cannot be conditionally required based on the HTTP method. However, you can define two different schemas for the GET and POST methods. Here's an example:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    MyScheduleGet:
      type: object
      properties:
        my_property:
          type: string
      required:
        - my_property
    MySchedulePost:
      type: object
      properties:
        my_property:
          type: string
paths:
  /schedule:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyScheduleGet'
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/MySchedulePost'
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Successful operation
```

In this example, `MyScheduleGet` schema requires `my_property`, while `MySchedulePost` schema does not. This way, `my_property` is required for GET but optional for POST. Please note that this is just a workaround, as OpenAPI does not inherently support different requirements based on the HTTP method. You might need to adjust this based on your actual API design and requirements.